# How do I change the background-color of a value depending on what it is through a .php file?

Tags: php, css, colors, background

I have a line of code that currently works like this:

```
$dimension = '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00"> T='.$thickness.'</span> X='.$x.' Y='.$y;
```

As you can see the value `$thickness` Is highlighted yellow. However `$thickness` is a value that changes to the following values: 1.90, 1.50, and 1.15.

How would I make each value have it's own background color?

Example= 1.90 = Yellow, 1.50 = Green, 1.15 = Blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$color = 'white';
if($thickness > 1.15) { $color = 'blue'; }
if($thickness > 1.5) { $color = 'green'; }
if($thickness > 1.9) { $color = 'yellow'; }
$dimension = '<span style="background-color: '.$color.'"> T='.$thickness.'</span> X='.$x.' Y='.$y;
```

Comment: Wow! thank you very much for the fast reply. Works great.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer! Also, you can replace the words with the hash tag color codes if you so desire.

Comment: It is marked! However I found one issue. the greater than symbols (>) was sometimes mixing up the colour for some reason but an easy fix for me was to make it greater than or equal to (>=) don't know if this was an issue for you. Also this is working with machinery and a database and the thickness was in ml, should have stated. So the 1.9 wasn't working so I had to add a 0.